# We want to implement a toggle Button as thumb within a html "slider" (input type="range")

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

We are developing an app with phonegap, where we want to have a toggle-button to turn off the slider completely.
Actually we can get a click event in our Desktop Browser on the thumb with the following code:

```
$(document).on('mouseup','.ui-slider-track .ui-btn.ui-slider-handle', function(){
           alert("click");
       });
```

(tap is actually not working, but click etc. is working too...)

but this code is not working for phonegap or in android-chrome.
My mobile device gets no event if I click on the thumb, except if I click on the very last pixel where the shadow begins.

Would be nice if you could help me with this problem :)

Comment: you want to disable _slider_? `$("slider_ID").slider("disable");`. if not, add HTML code.

Comment: Have you tried the vclick event - http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Comment: yeah we tried the vclick event but its not working, we just found a new solution to get this feature working thx guys.